# Plotting multiple graphs from multiple text files in python

Tags: python, plot, directory, operating-system

I have multiple text files in a directory. The 1st line of each text file is the header line. Rest of the lines are like columns containing different datas. I have to plot 7th column vs 5th column data graphs for each text file. I also want to plot all the graphs using a loop and a single code. Can anyone pls help me to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post an example of the data you have

Comment: please do not treat stack as a code writing service. You can with some looking around figure out yourself how to approach the problem. if you get some specific issue then please show the code and a specific question that people can help you with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NicoCaldo ... Here is one set of data ...         Year     Month     Date     Time   Deci Time     Wavelength     Max. Intensity     Optical Depth
2017      Dec       19     16:31      16.53      534.00           61719.63             0.06
2017      Dec       19     16:32      16.55      534.00           65535.00             0.00
2017      Dec       19     16:33      16.57      534.00           65535.00             0.00
2017      Dec       19     16:34      16.58      534.00           65535.00             0.00

Comment: @Sayak update the question, don't use comment for this kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` and `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
 
# sep= accepts the separator of your data i.e. ' ' space ',' comma etc
table = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.txt', sep=' ')

table.plot(x=['header_of_5th_col',y=['header_of_7th_col'])
```

I suggest also to check pandas documentations about [loading data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html) and [plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html) them

You can then loop the `table.plot` line of code to plot every graph you need

Answer (score 0):

code for getting all files in a specified directory:

```py
import os

files = os.listdir("path/to/directory")
print(files)
```

for reading the files I would suggest the library `pandas` ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/)) and for plotting `matplotlib` ([here](https://matplotlib.org/)).

for a more detailed solution more information on what exact data is given and what output is expected is needed.

for example sharing the first few lines of one of the files and a basic image created in paint or similar containing what things should roughly look like.